# Where can I get more storage probes?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

I currently only have 3 storage probes at the end of chapter 5. My miranium ticks for about 14k but my storage is only 17k. Where can I get more storage probes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the locations of every storage probe in the game:

Storage Probes:

- Chapter 3
- Chapter 4
- Chapter 6
- Chapter 11
- Kirsty quests (x3)
- Sylvalum : In a cave, north east of Spot 401
- Cauldros : On the edge, south segment under spot 514
- Complete Collectapedia of (blue crystal like) items in Cauldros

To get the Ares-90 (a strong post-game Skell) you only need 100k storage, which **does not require all the storage probes**. I'm mentioning this just so nobody feels compelled to grind out the Cauldros Collectapedia. It can be done as follows:[image]